# Stopping a service when the USB device is unplugged

Tags: android

I want to stop a running service when a usb is unplugged.

inside my activity `onCreate` I check the intent for its `action`

```
    if (getIntent().getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "************** USB unplugged stopping  service **********");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "usb was disconneced", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stopService(new Intent(this, myService.class));
    } else {
        init();
    }
```

And inside my `manifest` I have another `intent filter`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And this `intent filter` as well which is being called.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But the detach is not being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register a BroadcastReceiver

```
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
              Log.d(TAG, "************** USB unplugged stopping  service **********");
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "usb was disconneced", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  stopService(new Intent(this, myService.class));
           }
        };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: ok, but what happens when the activity is in the background, or being destroyed ?

Comment: register the receiver then for the service ;)

Comment: If you don't want to start broadcast receiver from an activity - define it in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm.. `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` is fired when a USB device (not the cable) is detached from the phone/tablet. This is not something you want.

I do not know if there is a straight forward API for detecting USB cable connections, but you can use [`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) and [`ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) to accomplish your goal.

Use following filters for your receiver:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And in your receiver, you can check the state and implement the logic you want:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch(intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)) {
            case 0: 
                // The device is running on battery
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:
                // Implement your logic
                break;
            case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:
                // Implement your logic
                break;
            case BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS:
                // Implement your logic
                break;
            default:
                // Unknown state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I stop a running service from a broadcastreceiver class??
And i'm running a usb device as a host.

Comment: thanks, I missed the context being passed as a parameter, but will the device detached will be called as well?

Comment: @user1940676 Not in this scenario, as it refers to “Android device got unplugged from PC”. When a USB OTG device is detached from the phone, you will get `USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`, provided you’re registered to receive that broadcast. In the latter case, `intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)` will give you the device that was disconnected.